# List-style-type Not Working

Tags: css

Attempting to add any formatting on the following site using the CSS "list-style-type" property for ul and ol elements seems not to have any effect. I've checked both CSS and HTML through several validators, and have been unable to determine what any errors might be. There do not appear to be any overrides in place to prevent them from being displayed.

```
http://74.220.219.55/~piedmoq6/patient-services/
http://74.220.219.55/~piedmoq6/wp-content/themes/piedmontpmr/style.css
http://74.220.219.55/~piedmoq6/wp-content/themes/piedmontpmr/normalize.css
```

Comment: Which list are you trying to add the `list-style-type` property to and what value are you assigning for this property?

Comment: you need your `<li>`s to be `display:list-item`, not `display:block`

Comment: Thanks, the "display:list-item" was it.